# Error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, typeerror, gmail-api, payload

The code shows email messages as belows:

```
       from __future__ import print_function
       import pickle
       import os.path
       from googleapiclient.discovery import build
       from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
       from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
       
       
       import base64
       from apiclient import errors
       import payload
       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
       
       
       
       messagecount=int(input("please write e-mail message number which want to see:"))
       
       
       # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
       SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
       
       
       
       creds = None
       # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
       # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
       # time.
       
       if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
           with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
       
       # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
       if not creds or not creds.valid:
           if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
              creds.refresh(Request())
           else:
              flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
             'Credentials.json', SCOPES)
              creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
              # Save the credentials for the next run
              with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                    pickle.dump(creds, token)
           
       service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
       
       # Call the Gmail API
       results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
       
       #Get Messages
       
       
       results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()
       messages = results.get('messages', [])
       
       message_count = messagecount
       for message in messages[:message_count]:
           msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
           # Use try-except to avoid any Errors
           try:
              # Get value of 'payload' from dictionary 'txt'
              payload = msg['payload']
              headers = payload['headers']
       
              # Look for Subject and Sender Email in the headers
              for d in headers:
                  if d['name'] == 'Subject':
                      subject = d['value']
                  if d['name'] == 'From':
                      sender = d['value']
       
              # The Body of the message is in Encrypted format. So, we have to decode it.
              # Get the data and decode it with base 64 decoder.
              
              parts = payload.get('parts')[0]
            
              data = parts['body']['data']
              data = data.replace("-","+").replace("_","/")
             
              decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
              
              # Now, the data obtained is in lxml. So, we will parse 
              # it with BeautifulSoup library
              soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_data , "lxml")
              body = soup.body()
            
              # Printing the subject, sender's email and message
              print("Subject: ", subject)
              print("From: ", sender)
              print("Message: ", body)
              print('\n')
           except errors:
               print("error")
```

Hello friends, the code reads some emails properly but stops somewhere and gives the following type error if I write only "except pass"  the error doesn't occur, ofcourse this is not a solution.

```
parts = payload.get('parts')[0]
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
How can I solve this problem? Could you fix it on code, please?

Comment: something like `if not payload.get('parts'): continue` should do the trick

Comment: it works, it doesn't give an error